# Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid - JqGridColumnEditTypes.Select - How send row id to action that load dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, jqgrid, lib.web.mvc

I'm using MVC5 and helper Lib.Web.Mvc.JQuery.JqGrid.
I need to load the list, into edit cell, without the current record, for to get one filtered list of the same type.

I have to get this:

- Category 1
- Category 1.1 *(current record)*
- Category 2
- Category 2.1
- Category 2.2

The list should show all categories except "Catergory 1.1".

The property affected, in my MODEL, is as follows:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
[JqGridColumnEditable(false)]
public int? CategoryPK { get; set; } 

[DisplayNameLocalized("Category")]
[JqGridColumnSortable(true, Index = "CategoryPK")]
[JqGridColumnEditable(true, "List4DDL", "Categories", EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.Select)]
[JqGridColumnFormatter("$.ddlFormatter")]
public string Category { get; set; }
```

My action into controller "Categories"

```
 public ActionResult List4DDL() {           
        var list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        try {
          ... my code to get list of categories
        } catch {
        ...
        }
        return (PartialView("_Partial.DropDownList", list));
   }
```

How can to send to action the edit row id, or the selected item, for get filtered list?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**!
Since it someone can have the same problem, i explain how did it.

I have modified, in my model, the dataannotation of property "Category" so:

```
[DisplayNameLocalized("Category")]
[JqGridColumnSortable(true, Index = "CategoryPK")]
[JqGridColumnEditable(true, "List4DDL", "Categories", EditType = JqGridColumnEditTypes.Select)]
[JqGridColumnFormatter("$.ddlFormatter", UnFormatter = "$.ddlUnFormatter")]
public string Category { get; set; }
```

Adding the attribute "UnFormatter", that is triggered when the cell is selected, after i have worked on view

Into view i have added this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {          
    @jqGrid.GetJavaScript(); 
    ... (other code fo my grid) ... 
    $.ddlUnFormatter =
        function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
            var recordID = -1;
            if (options) {
                if (options.rowId) {
                    recordID = options.rowId;
                }
                if (options.colModel) {
                    if (options.colModel.editoptions) {
                        if (options.colModel.editoptions.dataUrl && (options.colModel.editoptions.dataUrl.indexOf("?id=") < 1)) {
                            options.colModel.editoptions.dataUrl = options.colModel.editoptions.dataUrl + "?id=" + recordID;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return (cellvalue);
        };
</script>
```

i add the id on the fly on the route that load the list.
This is action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult List4DDL(int? id) {           
    var list = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    try {
      ... (my code to get list of categories, filtered by id)
    } catch {
    ...
    }
    return (PartialView("_Partial.DropDownList", list));
}
```

I hope i was helpful to someone.

Comment: Do not forget to dial in response.